# Concat two ActiveRecord::Relation instances in a sql friendly way

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm using ruby on rails with active record ORM, along with postgreSQL database. I have a search action in one of my controllers like this.

```
def search
    query = params[:q]
    query_regexp_str = ".?(" + query.split("").join(").?(") + ").?"
    query_regexp = Regexp.new(query_regexp_str)
    results = Company.where("symbol ~* ?", query_regexp_str)
    render json: results, each_serializer: CompanySearchSerializer
end
```

This very loosely matches company symbols with the input query. It works fine except sometimes the symbol that is fully matching the query appears somewhere in the middle of results which is expected from the above code.

I was thinking of writing something like this.

```
def search
    query = params[:q]
    query_regexp_str = ".?(" + query.split("").join(").?(") + ").?"
    query_regexp = Regexp.new(query_regexp_str)
    full_match_results = Company.where(symbol: query)
    other_results = Company.where("symbol ~* ?", query_regexp_str)

    # Somehow concatenate the two and put it in results variable
    render json: results, each_serializer: CompanySearchSerializer
end
```

**Note:** I don't want to use ruby array methods like `+` and write something like this: `results = full_match_results + other_results`, becasue I want to take advantage of **SQL** and **Active Record** and only at the end, convert the results to json.

Are active record relations concatenateable and by that I don't mean using `merge` or `or` method. If not, Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you say "combine" the results, do you mean with an `AND` or an `OR`?

Comment: Neither. Bad wording sorry. I don't wanna combine. I simply wanna concat them.

Comment: That sounds the same as using an `or` in sql...

Comment: Yeah but I'm not trying to do that. I wanna do what `+` does with arrays. But in a sql friendly way and without converting them into arrays. If I have `[5, 7]` and `[3, 1]`. I'm looking for a way to get `[5, 7, 3, 1]`. But with `ActiveRecord::Relation` instances

Comment: I say that because I tried `merge` and `or` which use sql `AND` and `OR` and the fully matched symbol still appeared in the middle of the results

Comment: `or` _doesn't_ convert them into arrays, it works through AR. Try the following:
`Company.where(symbol: query).to_sql`
`Company.where("symbol ~* ?", query_regexp_str).to_sql`
`Company.where(symbol: query).or(Company.where("symbol ~* ?", query_regexp_str)).to_sql`
And you'll see what sql they're executing. The whole point of the `or` method is to allow you to do this through AR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189157/discussion-between-glyoko-and-amiratak88).